# How do I automate folder location and file name in Access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to substitute the hard codes between the 2 underlined area in VB as indicated,  so that it fetches the excel file automatically with code and transfers the spreadsheet into an Ms-Access table with same fields.  IT should be able to do this function automatically with vb codes in MS-Access.

```
Dim fso As Object  'FileSystemObject
Dim f As Object  'File
Dim strTempPath As String
Dim objExcel As Object  'Excel.Application
Dim objWorkbook As Object  'Excel.Workbook
Const TemporaryFolder = 2

On Error Resume Next
StrSQL = "DELETE * FROM bed_code_tbl"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  'New FileSystemObject
strTempPath = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder) & "\" & fso.GetTempName & "\"
fso.CreateFolder strTempPath
'------------------------------------------------------

Set f = fso.GetFile("C:\Users\johnpfe\Documents\Bed_code_tbl.xlsx")
fso.CopyFile f.Path, strTempPath & f.Name
'--------------------------------------------------------

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  ' New Excel.Application
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strTempPath & f.Name)
objWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C100").Select
objWorkbook.Save
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "bed_code_tbl", 
strTempPath & f.Name, True

fso.DeleteFile strTempPath & f.Name
fso.DeleteFolder Left(strTempPath, Len(strTempPath) - 1)

Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

End Sub
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Substitute *with what*?  The simple answer is to initialize a string variable (possibly inside a loop) and then set that string variable to the desired file path.

Comment: Do you perhaps want the folder location returned by `CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Mydocuments")` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're trying to find the current user's documents folder.
You can use the eviron() function. More on that if you follow these links.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264486(v=office.15).aspx
http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4296

```
Dim fso As Object  'FileSystemObject
Dim f As Object  'File
Dim strTempPath As String
Dim objExcel As Object  'Excel.Application
Dim objWorkbook As Object  'Excel.Workbook
Const TemporaryFolder = 2

On Error Resume Next
strSQL = "DELETE * FROM bed_code_tbl"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  'New FileSystemObject
strTempPath = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder) & "\" & fso.GetTempName & "\"
fso.CreateFolder strTempPath
'------------------------------------------------------

Set f = fso.GetFile(Environ("UserProfile") & "\Documents\Bed_code_tbl.xlsx")
fso.CopyFile f.Path, strTempPath & f.NAME
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get folder location for Your access file. And place created file relative to that location.

Alternatively ask user for the location.